# came ... at his evening paper

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 'evening paper' mean in passage "came ... at his evening paper"?

> That night came Aunt Ellen, gentle, sentimental, wrinkled, sighing,
>   oppressed by wealth, in to Brother Anthony **at his evening paper**, and
>   began discourse on the subject of lovers’ woes.

Mammon and the Archer
by O. Henry

Answer (score 1):

It's old fashioned and literary but it means nothing very special.  He is reading an evening newspaper.

Some papers are published in the morning and some are published in the evening.  A [WSJ article](https://www.wsj.com/articles/the-last-of-the-afternoon-newspapers-evening-yellowstone-livingston-delivery-montana-news-extinct-media-local-town-11650401205) notes that these were once very common.  It could also have been an afternoon edition of one of the major New York papers, or a resold copy of a morning paper (buying and reselling newspapers was a common way of being frugal).